# Valid values for EGLNativeWindowType on Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, egl

How to init EGLNativeWindowType in order to create an Android Native OpenGL ES 3.0 app?

I haven't found any place documenting the valid values for EGLNativeWindowType. I'm reading OpenGL ES 3.0 programming guide 2nd ed. and I also googled many (far too many) terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One does not simply create a native window on Android.  You have to talk to the screen compositor.  It used to be the case that a program running as root could open the framebuffer device if the app framework wasn't running, but that's (a) not very useful, and (b) not going to work on devices that don't have fbdev.

You need to get a window from the system, and use that.  There's an example in the [NativeActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, hopefully I'll be able to figure out theright config soon :-) .  How does the calling Java method know what is the 'app' param that is passed to the main C func? I saw that the window type is there, inside the app structure, which is not defined in the above code. Btw, in the book I read they're not doing it simply, but there are two params that I do have to init in order to run their code and I don't know one of them - the one I mentioned in the Q.

Comment: Ok, I think I understood something: in order to work with events in Android native app, I have to create android native activity. This activity will get the param from the system in the engine->app->window field. Is it correct?

Comment: completely misunderstood it first. For those who're interested and following my monolog here: there is a main method that Android Native API runs when you tell it to start from the native main func by telling it that you don't have java code in your manifest and working with the native Activity. When it will launch the native activity, it will also pass it a C structure with everything you (I) need(ed), just like in link from the above answer.